# how to build third party custom keyboard with cordova/phonegap

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, keyboard, ios8

iOS8 giving option to build custom third-party keyboard https://www.apple.com/uk/ios/ios8/quicktype/

Is it possible to build third party custom keyboard application for **iOS8** with this **cordova** or **phonegap** ?

Actually I'm looking to build foreign language keyboard for iOS8, is there any solution or any plugin available for that ?
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Comment: Hello! Have you made any research progress?

Comment: @Beat I have stopped the idea because it wasn't possible at that time. Not sure about the current phonegap version. Don't forget to answer here if you get solution for it

Comment: @Beat http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how-to-build-third-party-custom-keyboard-with-cordova-phonegap